# How to refresh Java Applet?

Tags: applet

I'm trying to use Java Applet for my website.
but I have a problem with refresh java applet content.

here is my code, (AppletTest.java)

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class AppletTest extends Applet{

    public void init(){

    }

    public void stop(){

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("ABC",20,20); //I will draw DEF and FFF after ABC.
    }

}
```

and HTML is (appletTest.html)

```
 <body>
  <applet code="AppletTest.class" name='AppletTest' width='500' height='300' style='border:1px solid #cdcdcdl'>
    <param name='cache_option' value='no'> // I put this code to avoid browser remember applet but it does not work. :(
  </applet>
 </body>
```

Firstly I draw 'ABC' and It draw well.

and I change 'ABC' to 'DEF' and compile again and run it.

it draw 'DEF' well. And I change 'DEF' to 'FFF' and compile and run.

but it does not change to 'FFF'. it still 'DEF'. I refresh the page many time but it is not changed.

I think my browser remember pre applet content. so to avoid it, I put the `<param name='cache_option' value='no'>` code into applet tag. but it does not work...

anybody know this, please advice me.

Thank you!

Comment: I took a random guess as to the nature of your question.  I don't like guessing.  Don't forget to ask a question in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applets should be tested in tools like applet viewer or [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/), which do not cache classes.  If testing in a browser, ensure the Java Console is open (there is an option in the Java Control Panel) & type Ctrl-X (I think that is 'clear class cache') before refreshing the page.

---

> I put the `<param name='cache_option' value='no'>` code into applet tag..

That only works with [recent JREs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/applet-caching.html).  What [JRE version](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.vendor.url%2Cjava.version%2Cjava.vm.specification.version%2Cjava.vm.version&format=TSV) has the user got installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable Java Console (Java Control Panel>Advanced>Java Console>Show console) and after every new compilation you can use 'x' option in this console to clear classloader cache. Then simply click refresh on the website and that's all.